# lambda expression trying to query one list based on another

Tags: c#, lambda

After some advice on how to do this nicely using lambda expressions.

What I want is to get a list of placements based on an agency. I want the placements where the placement.agency  != agency but where placement.agencypersonnel contains any of the agency staff.

So where the placement is not for that agency, but there are staff from that agency involved in another agency's placement

I don't know how to query based on the second condition.

So something like:

```
// agency is being passed in
     var agencySupervisors = agency.AgencyPersonnel;

     return agency.Placements
            .Where(p => p.Supervisors.Contains(agencySupervisors))
            .Where(p => p.Agency != agency);
```

I get that Contains is supposed to refer to a single object rather than a collection - which is why its erroring.. but I'm not sure how to get it to check against all objects in the collection.

Have also tried Any

```
 return agency.Placements
           .Where(p => agencySupervisors.Any<PlacementSupervisor>(p.Supervisors))
           .Where(p => p.Agency != agency);
```

So hopefully its just I'm using the wrong one!!

Another spanner in the works is trying to figure out how the placement supervisor and the agency personnel entities relate to one another.. I think its linked on AgencyPersonnelId = SupervisorId so I'm guessing that will also have to be factored into my expression.

Thanks!

**Edit: How do I handle if the type of objects in the two list aren't the same - but I know that the Id will match.  Do I have to write a comparer and somehow incorporate that into the expression?? ie. AgencyPersonnelId = SupervisorId**

I have tried:

```
return placements
                .Where(p => p.Supervisors.Any(supervisor => agencySupervisors.Any(ap => ap.AgencyPersonnelId == supervisor.SupervisorId)));
```

But it is giving me no results so it is obviously wrong.

**Edit: Actually when I try to iterate through the placements in the returned collection I'm getting a null reference exception - so I'm not sure if its something to do with my expression or the way I'm returning the results.**

Comment: Would agency.Placements ever contain placements that doesn't belong to that agengy? If not does Suprvisors have references to all the placements they are involved in?

Comment: Hmm good point thanks!   Unfortunately Supervisors don't have references to all the placements they are involved in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help - Because the objects were of different types I ended up having to do something a little different - but then found I was able to use their Ids for the comparison so the result was:

```
var agencySupervisors = (from ap in agency.AgencyPersonnel
                                    where ap != null
                                        select ap.AgencyPersonnelId).ToList();

            return 
                (from p in m_PlacementRepository.Linq orderby p.PlacementId select p)
                .Where(p => p.Agency != agency)
                .Where(p => p.Supervisors != null && p.Supervisors.Any(s => agencySupervisors.Contains(s.SupervisorId)));
```

Plus as Mikael rightly pointed out I was starting with the wrong collection in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

You are close with `Any` & `Contains` - try both at once

```
return agency.Placements        
    .Where(p => agencySupervisors.Any(supervisor => p.Supervisors.Contains(supervisor))
    .Where(p => p.Agency != agency);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `.Intersect` also:

```
return agency.Placements
         .Where(p => agencySupervisors.Intersect(p.Supervisors).Any()
                     && p.Agency != agency);
```